# Automated hosting

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, nameserver, dns-servers

I'm going to make a web service, where people can register domain names and host their sites, which they order from us. Also I need proper billing. For this purposes I'm going to buy Hetzner root server with Parralels Plesk panel.

What other software do I need to setup or which services I need to use? Especially I'm interested about DNS setup and nameservers setup.

Comment: You should consider recruiting someone who has past experiences in setting similar services or consult with an agency that will provide this information.. There is just far to many things involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same server to also manage your DNS and nameservers, as Plesk provides this feature in the DNS Settings for each domain. It's recommended however that you use separate DNS servers so that there isn't a single point of failure (i.e., the nameservers will still be reachable if the web server temporarily goes down).

For DNS service providers, that might generate a debate if I suggest some...but it's easy enough to search for them in Google.

Parallels offers a [Customer & Business Manager](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/billing/) add-on to Plesk. This might be available from your web hosting company, but if not, Parallels sells a license for it on their site for a monthly fee:  [Hoster Management Pack](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/pricing-licensing/)

That would do much to automate things, as Plesk alone does not include things like automated account setup, sales, invoicing, etc...